# Blocking and unblocking text box on time basis

Tags: javascript, php

I am blocking few textbox values at 10:00 PM every night. It has to get available only next day 8:00 AM.

I am taking the server time not client's time. Blocking, I achieved without any error, but not getting how to re-open every next day morning 8:00 AM

for blocking on an hourly basis, I have done like this

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$current_date = date('H:i:s');
$fdate = '22:00:00';

if($current_date >= $fdate) { 
//block text box 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you mean by textbox but I assume you are talking about an input.

You can give your input a `disabled` attribute if you want to block usage of a certain input box.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput">
```

Javascript:

```
if($current_date >= $fdate) { 
  //block text box 
  document.getElementById("myInput").disabled = "true";
}
```

To unblock:

```
document.getElementById("myInput").disabled = "";
```

Comment: enable and disable i can do it. But while enabling, it should check the time every next morning 8:00 AM . That i am not getting